# Change font style when typing in powerpont

Tags: powerpoint

I am using PowerPoint2013 for create a presentation about math. And I do not want to use "equation object". I chose Italic time new roman font and I write for example A=(a1,a2,...) but it show me *A=(a1,a2,...)* instead of *A=*(*a1,a2,*...). Except letters, other characters not to be italic style.
So if a character (that I write) be a letter then automatically must be show italic style, and if not, must be show normal style.
How can I do.

Comment: How about *A=(a¹, a², a³ ...)* or *A=(a₁, a₂, a₃ ...)* ? Would that do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll present a few options here:

**VBA**

You could use VBA to italicise only the letters on a slide. If this is something that could be useful then let me know and I'll give you a few pointers. A few downsides though:

- It wouldn't work in real time. Also, not all letters should be italicised when typesetting math; for example, cos(*x*).
- It still won't look great. Times is not a mathematical font.

**Beamer**

Most university lecturers will use LaTeX with Beamer to create mathematical presentations. It will export each slide as a static .pdf (i.e. you won't be able to use animation other than things appearing one by one), but will look much more professional than powerpoint, and you will be able to take advantage of LaTeX's wonderful maths typesetting.

**TeXPoint**

I haven't used this myself, but it is a plugin for powerpoint which lets you use LaTeX to typeset equations: http://texpoint.necula.org/

Out of interest, why do you not want to use PowerPoint's built-in equation editor?